# D3 adding/positioning text

Tags: javascript, d3.js, treemap

Hi I’m trying to figure out if it’s possible to do the following:

[image]

As you can see by the picture, I want to have text to appear once in the middle of each “section” (different colours) on the chart. Is it possible to do this with D3? If so how would I achieve it. Any help would be appreciated.

Currently I've managed to have it appear on each individual rectangle, like so?
[image]

Here's where i add the text:

```
     cell.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.dx / 2; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d.dy / 2; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text("test")
       .style("opacity", function(d) { console.log(this.getComputedTextLength());d.w = this.getComputedTextLength(); return d.dx > d.w ? 1 : 0; });
```

Here's the complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/noobiecode/9ev9qjt3/74/

Comment: Please add some code or, preferably, set up a [mcve] as a JSFiddle or the like.

Comment: I thought i had added but fiddle url but guess i was wrong. I've edited the question so it's added now.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code it's hard to answer, but how about you start with adding `.attr("text-anchor", "middle")` to your text elements?

Comment: I've tried that but all that does is add the text to the middle of each rectangle which is not what i want. I want to have it in the middle of each group (look at image one where i ask the question).